# Styling links according to link.label in zoomcharts library

Tags: hyperlink, styling, zoomcharts

Trying to style links ..

chart has

```
        linkRules:{"rule1":linkStyle},
```

and function defined as such

```
        function linkStyle(link){
            switch (link.label)
            {
            case "Executes": 
                link.fillColor = "blue";
                link.radius = 4;

            case "Benefits": 
                link.fillColor =  "green";
                link.radius = 2;

            default:
                link.fillColor = "#000000";
                link.radius = 1;
            };
            link.toDecoration="arrow";
        }
```

but not working as expected..

Comment: and what is not working? what says the console. put console.log(link) within the function. check this example for link styling: https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/net-chart/examples/style/arrows.html

Comment: values for fillColor and radius are not applied. log shows this for a link with label "Benefits" http://snag.gy/MIXvM.jpg . Also checked this example https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/net-chart/examples/style/colors.html .

Comment: what is strange that if I add the statement from the color example at the end of my own function, colors are applied ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it :)  I overlooked to include the "break;" statement and the end of each case.

```
        function linkStyle(link){
            switch (link.label)
            {
            case "Executes": 
                link.fillColor = "blue";
                link.radius = 4;
                break;  
            case "Benefits": 
                link.fillColor =  "green";
                link.radius = 2;
                break;  
            default:
                link.fillColor = "#000000";
                link.radius = 1;
            };
            link.toDecoration="arrow";
        }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I am the author of the question :)

Comment: Then if you have resolved your problem, the right way is not to update the original question but to publish the solution as an answer. What you wrote here is more a comment not a real answer (solution), I suggest you post the correct code (including the break statements) in this answer.